# Why isn't my application receiving broadcast packets?

Tags: networking, fedora, udp, broadcast

I have written a [Qt application](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare) that listens for UDP broadcast packets on the network interface `p2p1`. I have installed the application in Fedora 17 i386 in a VirtualBox VM. For some reason, the application is not receiving any broadcast packets that I am sending.

I installed and ran Wireshark and verified that the broadcast packets are indeed arriving on `p2p1`:

[image: image description]

Does anyone have any idea why the application (which is listening for UDP packets on port `41720`) isn't receiving any of the packets? Some security setting or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following set of steps were able to resolve the problem:

1. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   system-config-firewall
   ```
2. Enter your password if prompted.
3. Click "Other Ports" on the left-hand side:
   [image]
4. Click the "Add" button on the right-hand side:
   [image]
5. Check "User Defined" and enter the values below:
   [image]
6. Click "OK" and then click the "Apply" button in the toolbar:
   [image]
7. If you are warned that selecting "Yes" will override any existing firewall configuration, you may safely click "Yes".

<sub><sub>Note: the above instructions were copied from [this page](http://quickmediasolutions.com/blog/8/how-to-run-nitroshare-on-fedora-17), which I am the author of.</sub></sub>