# QT application doesn't receive udp broadcast since linux kernel 3.13.0-70

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, qt, wireshark

I'm developing a QT application on Ubuntu and suddenly had problems because QT app doesn't receive UDP broadcast messages. They are visible in Wireshark on that machine, but never received in QT.

Since my collegae started to have the same problem with his machine a few days ago, we investigated this further and found out that returning to kernel 3.13.0-68 solves the problem!

How should we solve this permanently? Report this to Linux devs?!

FYI, no firewall in use so not related to this question: [Why isn't my application receiving broadcast packets?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/why-isnt-my-application-receiving-broadcast-packets)

Best regards,
Frank